# Linux keyboard listeners

Tags: linux, keyboard

I'm trying to change some keyboard shortcuts like the power-button and  + .
I know that my WM (Window Manager) handle part of the shortcuts, but  and power-button shortcuts aren't mapped in any of my WM shortcuts files (at least I didn't find any of those).

I think "someone" in a lower level (maybe the kernel? I don't know) is listening the keyboard, because even in text mode (without running my WM),  and power-button still work (like, I can +/- the screen brightness, I can toggle wireless on/off and so on (except for the sound, those are handled by the WM).

So, my question is: Who are (usually) all the possible listeners of the keyboard in the system? And where are the configuration files?

Some system information:

- Notebook Asus eee-pc 1201n
- Slackware 14.0
- Linux 3.2.28
- Fluxbox WM

Comment: Don't forget the firmware. It listens to *everything*.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few of them please take a look at

- [How to get special keys to work](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_get_special_keys_to_work#Overview)
- [LaptopSpecialKeys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopSpecialKeys)